# How to decide learning rate, iterations in ADVI with adam?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, optimization, gradient-descent

I am Automatic Differentiation Variational Inference for bayesian inference using PyMC. I am using ADAM optimizer learning rate = 0.0005, number of monte carlo objects = 2, 20,000 iterations and full batch. Below is the -log(loss) graph.

[image]

It took 24 hours to run the above optimization process. I wonder what is the best value for learning rate and other parameters to make it faster and less noisy?